# Выполнение фоновых задач без пользовательского запроса на RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Я пишу браузерную игру и задача:

- когда пользователь нажимает "Пойти в поход" он выбирает время длительности похода.
- во время похода, вне зависимости от действий пользователя надо генерить разные события на сервере, фоном.
- во время похода, при обновлении страницы можно увидеть Логи. Что происходило в походе и оно постоянно пополняется, если что-то случается.
- за всё время похода, например, за 1 час, может случиться как 5, так и 50 событий.

Как добиться выполнение плановых операций на фоне? Не по запросу HTTP, как например, при обновлении страницы.

И как сделать, чтоб операция выполнялось определенное кол-во времени?

А чтоб это выполнялось даже когда пользователь не в сети и для множества пользователей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользоваться сервисом типа Sidekiq
https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidekiq